Import some EML files into NSF IBM Notes using interop.domino.dll?
I want to import some eml files into Lotus Notes NSF file using interop.domino.dll, but didn't find any way. Can you suggest me some C# code solutions to do this?
I know it is possible with interop.domino.dll, maybe using MIME, but I don't know the process.
